# Javascript Pix Gallery call for local folder

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in javascript, I want to convert a picture gallery to use pictures from a local folder instead of flickr api.
Can someone help me with it?

Here is the code:

```js
!(function(){
    'use strict';

 var numOfImages = window.location.search ? parseInt(window.location.search.match(/\d+$/)[0]) : 70,
  gallery = $('#gallery'),
  videos = [
   {
    title: "Victoria's Secret",
    url: "http://player.vimeo.com/video/8974462?byline=0&portrait=0",
    thumb: "http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/432/699/43269900_100.jpg"
   },
   {
    title: "PEOPLE ARE AWESOME 2013 FULL HD ",
    url: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/W3OQgh_h4U4",
    thumb: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/W3OQgh_h4U4/0.jpg"
   },
   {
    title: "Biting Elbows - 'Bad Motherfucker' Official Music Video",
    url: "http://player.vimeo.com/video/62092214?byline=0&portrait=0",
    thumb: "http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/431/797/431797120_100.jpg"
   }
  ];
  
    // Get some photos from Flickr for the demo
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
   per_page : numOfImages,
            api_key: 'b51d3a7c3988ba6052e25cb152aecba2' // this is my own API key, please use yours
        },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
    })
 .done(function (data){
        var loadedIndex = 1, isVideo;
  
  // add the videos to the collection
  data.photos.photo = data.photos.photo.concat(videos);
  
        $.each( data.photos.photo, function(index, photo){
   isVideo = photo.thumb ? true : false;
   // http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html
            var url = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret,
    img = document.createElement('img');
   
   // lazy show the photos one by one
   img.onload = function(e){
    img.onload = null;
    var link = document.createElement('a'),
    li = document.createElement('li')
    link.href = this.largeUrl;

    link.appendChild(this);
    if( this.isVideo ){
     link.rel = 'video';
     li.className = 'video'
    }
    li.appendChild(link);
    gallery[0].appendChild(li);
   
    setTimeout( function(){ 
     $(li).addClass('loaded');
    }, 25*loadedIndex++);
   };
   
   img['largeUrl'] = isVideo ? photo.url : url + '_b.jpg';
   img['isVideo'] = isVideo;
   img.src = isVideo ? photo.thumb : url + '_t.jpg';
   img.title = photo.title;
        });

  // finally, initialize photobox on all retrieved images
  $('#gallery').photobox('a', { thumbs:true }, callback);
  // using setTimeout to make sure all images were in the DOM, before the history.load() function is looking them up to match the url hash
  setTimeout(window._photobox.history.load, 1000);
  function callback(){
   console.log('callback for loaded content:', this);
  };
    });
})();
```

I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You need server code to read the directory and create the data to return. Unless you manually want to create the data

Comment: I want to use a folder from my website server, godaddy server.
"../images/projects/else_rd/"

Comment: @charlietfl what code from the server, can you explain please?

Comment: So you need to use whatever server side programming language you have available to read that directory and create the data from it. Which language would depend on type of hosting package

Comment: how about to create the data manually? @charlietfl